# Regionalisation Design Patterns in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, internationalization, mono, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on creating a GUI for an interface that will be used in several languages.

The environment I am working in is Unity 4.2 with Mono C#. The application must remain very cross platform compatible (including web, ios, Linux, windows).

What I am trying to achieve is a nice way of handling the multiple languages, allowing for the easy addition of an extra language, or an extra field. If I were working in ruby or python, I believe this may be a decent solution;

```
class RegionalDB:
    def __init__(self):
        # Maybe connect to a data source such as a db, or files

    def set_language(self, lang):
        # Verify we have this lang, error if not
        # Set an attribute on self for every field entry in this language

text = RegionalDB()
text.set_language('de')

print text.exit_button
```

The above method would allow me to use the powerful features of python objects being able to dynamically assign members at runtime. The code above would print, in German, the text that was in the "exit_button" field of the data source. In ruby I could do similar, or I could use the attribute_missing function to query the data source directly instead of assigning all variables in memory at once to the object.

Unfortunately C#'s Reflection code is not quite as elegant as the scripts mentioned above. So my issues are as follows;

1. Creating an elegant, maintainable, regionalisation tool in a compiled, strongly typed language.
2. Storing the data for the languages in an effective manner using unity

With issue 1. I have been unable to find a design pattern, or much information at all to be honest.

Issue 2. I believe can be solved with some unity editor programming, but I have not touched this topic much and am open to suggestions.

So in question form;

1. Does anybody know of any design patterns that would work well with C# for regionalisation
2. Any suggestions on a way forward with an interface/storage mechanism in the unity editor

Thanks.

P.S. I must be able to change language at runtime

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of C# apps out there which already have l10n support.

I would divide them in three types:

1. Resources-based internationalization: Texts are stored in XML files. This is the *Microsoft way*.
2. PO-based internationalization: Using the long-stablished **gettext** technology which includes many Unixy tools to deal with updating original texts and translations. You can see how this works by taking a look at the code of some Mono desktop app (i.e.: [Banshee](https://github.com/GNOME/banshee)), and look for the Catalog.GetString() calls, which use the Mono.Posix assembly as a linked reference.
3. [Vernacular](https://github.com/rdio/vernacular)-based internationalization: used in mobile apps to abstract each mobile-platform localization details and have a common method across all.

In my particular opinion, the best and most modern method is the latter. But if you're targetting a desktop app, I guess you can create/contribute a new Vernacular backend to fit this purpose.